# Deleting one of two foreign keys in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I mistakenly added two foreign keys in one table in MySQL even though I proceeded in the described manner to create one foreign key only. But that aside, the problem is that I need to remove the foreign key which is NOHOW related to the main table in the database which the primary keys are referenced from.
That is, I need to remove the field CId from customer table.

[Tables' image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOh6l.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to first use

```
 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

then you can drop the foreign key

```
 ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> DROP CONSTRAINT <FOREIGN_KEY_NAME>
```

And then make sure you set foreign keys back using

```
 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```